# Replace Apple In-App purchase with custom bitcoin based prefill system?

Tags: in-app-purchase

Am I allowed to use in my iOS app a prepay system, where user can upload bitcoin to use in-app premium services? I want to avoid pay 30% for Apple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#purchasing-currencies) (under section 11.2), anything that circumvents the in-app purchase API can and likely will be pulled and/or rejected. Going around Apple and using your own system would be a bad idea with the possibility of you being ejected from the developer program.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Do you think it is a workaround if the there are a standard level of services available, and if you 'log in to your account' was created on web, then you can get extra / premium services, so the purchase chould have been on the web?!

Comment: This is just conjecture, but I'd imagine that as long as the browser-based web front-end existed before you submit the app to the App Store, that could be a valid course of action! That also opens you up to alternative forms of payment rather than using strictly Bitcoin. Just know you would then have to maintain a secure database and login system for users, which could be more expensive for you short term.

Comment: right, maybe with bitcoin payment implementation is easier, as I understand, bitcoin system stores all transactions, so I could chech a certain transaction - offered by payer - state, if it is DONE, I would assign content to the payer